# ESD / TVS / Over-voltage diode selection - leakage current into power supply

Tags: diodes, esd, flyback, tvs

I am choosing an over-voltage protection diodes for input pins to a device. There will also be spark gaps on these lines.

My question is what kind of effect will the leakage current of the diode have on the power supply. I have already read that for battery supplies the battery life can be affected / reduced.

Answer (score 1):

The leakage current of diodes produces a constant current flow. It's defined for conditions where the diode is not actually in *conducting state*. Thus, these diodes rise your total power consumption like a parallel resistor.
Normally this current is very low, we are talking about \$nA\$ or \$\mu A\$.
However, this values depends on your type of diode and e.g. the clamping voltage of TVS diodes. In generally, it's defined in the datasheet.

Comment: Ah I was being dumb and thinking that leakage was flowing into the supply, but it actually flows in the reverse direction.. makes more sense now.